# Controlling jupyter kernel display names in Anaconda on win10

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to do development on Jupyter notebooks that will be deployed to mybinder.org .  The deployment process depends on the notebook being saved with the display name of the kernel being "Python 2" or "Python 3".  Anything else causes a disruptive prompt for the end user.

I installed the latest anaconda3 distribution and found that both the default kernel name and the ones I get when I set up a conda subenvironmnet are a lot more verbose than that. I can name an environment "Python 3" for instance but the display name of the kernel is some long string mentioning conda.

I tried setting up a kernelspec using ipython directly but the jupyter notebook command on my development machine is ignoring it.  It appears to be querying something in conda-land that isn't a kernelspec json file.

Any suggestions?  I need a way to set up a jupyter kernel with a specific name and I"m not finding any clues.  This seems like a new(ish) problem, I think I've done this before in Windows but I don't have a definite recollection.

Comment: conda registers kernels in its environments automatically. It does so using the `nb_conda_kernels` package. If you nuke it, you should be left with only the kernels you registered manually.